# File.Exists returns true on file name only

Tags: .net, vb.net, system.io.file

I am currently debugging an application, where the following code returns true on the file name only.

```
If Not IO.File.Exists(out) Then
    '' Work
End If
```

The watches for this execution is as follows:

[image]

How is this statement validated as true, when the actual file is located fairly deep on a network drive? I'd assume that this could be true, if the file was located in the same directory as my execution.

Comment: what is `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` ? is it the location with the file?

Comment: Never check if a file exists by file name alone. Use Path.Combine with the folder/directory and filename.

Comment: Also, click the blue refresh icon `↻` from your screenshot to ensure the value is up-to-date.

Comment: All done; found the file in the bin folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Documentation: [`File.Exists`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.exists?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_File_Exists_System_String_)

> the path parameter is permitted to specify **relative or absolute** path
>   information. Relative path information is interpreted as **relative to
>   the current working directory**. To obtain the current working
>   directory, see [`GetCurrentDirectory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_Directory_GetCurrentDirectory).

So if there is no path but only the file, the path is the current working directory of the application.

Comment: The current directory is the bin folder of my project. I see that the file has somehow ended up here giving that there are more issues with storing the files.

I have been looking in the folder before; but i guess I was too fast.

Thanks for the answer.

Comment: _"the file has somehow ended up here"_ You probably did the same mistake somewhere else, that is, you passed the same _relative_ path to another method which is supposed to **create** the file. Double-check your code and make sure you never pass a filename only _unless_ that's the intended behavior _and_ you know you'll have write permissions to `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory`; actually, even in this case, I would recommend using the full path (i.e., `Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), filename)`).